# how to add a dynamic horizontal scroll to ant design table where the columns are dynamic(not sure about the number of columns)

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am able to add columns dynamically, tried to fix the scroll based on     the number of columns but the column title length may also increase which 
causes the text in the title to move to the next line.

```
  <Table
    className="manageUserList"
    pagination={false}
    rowKey={record => {return record.key;}}
    scroll={
    columns.length < 4
    ? { x: 0 }
    : columns.length < 6
    ? { x: 1000 }
    : columns.length > 6 && columns.length <= 12
    ? { x: 1400 }
    : { x: 2000 }
    }
    rowSelection={rowSelection}
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={this.state.data}
    />
```

some of the columns have more width and some are too less such that the    text goes to the next line.need the text to be spread in one line for all  columns regardless of the number of columns and the width of columns. The 
    scroll should expand the columns equally

Comment: Hi, make a simple example in a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/s/new and I'll try to help

Comment: Did you ever get this working @sam024?